# Find width of the biggest rectangle in a sector

Tags: circles, rectangles

Is it possible to find the width and starting coordinates of the biggest horizontal rectangle of a fixed height inscribed in a given sector with any angle?

[image: Sector with an inscribed rectangle.]

This is actually to do with computer programming. I am creating a pie chart and the rectangle is supposed to hold a label relating to the information represented by the sector. 
I can measure the width of the text(of constant height) that I want to place within the rectangle. If I can find the width of the widest horizontally placed rectangle of a given height, I can decide if the label would fit completely within the sector. If not, it would need to be moved outside of the circle.
The sector has a variable angle as in a pie chart different sectors have different angles.

I am not too good at geometry, so I thought of asking here. Please let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: Yes, but I would say that the positioning of your sector around the circle will give distinct answers even for the same inner angle. Your left- or right-most 30 degrees sector will allow a longer word compared to your upper- or lower-most 30 degrees sector.

Comment: @Shakti Prakash Singh Of biggest area?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose at least 3 vertices of the rectangle must be on the radii and circular arc.

*"Horizontal"* has no meaning in this context of bounded area maximization. The procedure should be valid for arbitrary rotation/ translations of the sector.

When sector is acute angled, angle bisector serves as basis giving max area of a sector/pie as shown below:

$(s,c,t)$ short hand for $(\sin\theta,  \cos\theta,\tan\theta). $

Wlog, one side can be taken  along x-axis. Coordinates of required point $(c,s,\theta)$ and for sector endpoint $(x_1,y_1,\alpha)$

Equations of end radius and intermediate radius are

$$ y= s_1/c_1,\quad y=s\,$$ cutting at

$$ s=t_1$$

$$Area= s(c- s /t_1)$$

To find max area differentiate with resp to argument $\theta$.  By Chain Rule

$$ \dfrac{s}{c-s/t_1}=\dfrac{c}{s+c/t}$$

Cross multiply and simplify

$$ \tan \alpha = \tan 2 \theta ,\quad\boxed{\theta= \alpha/2}$$

So we need to bisect the central sector angle to arrive at lead points to further draw as you indicated towards the rectangle.

[image]

To draw pie of maximum rectangular area of an *obtuse central angle* bisect the sectors and bisect the half sector yet again. Join the quatrasector points and their perpendiculars as shown in the required maximum rectangle $PQRS$.